# How to list shared remote desktop drives

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, remote-desktop

In my MS-Access application (which runs on a Windows 2012R2 server) I need to check which local drives have been shared by my Remote Users in the Remote Desktop Local Devices and Resources tab.

I tried this:

```vb
Dim wql As String, SrvEx As Object, WMIObj As Object, WMIObjEx As Object

wql = "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk"
Set SrvEx = GetObject("winmgmts:root/CIMV2")
Set WMIObj = SrvEx.ExecQuery(wql)
For Each WMIObjEx In WMIObj
    Me.Text1 = Me.Text1 & WMIObjEx.Path_.RelPath & vbCrLf
Next
```

This  lists the physical drives on the remote server, not the drives that have been shared.

I tried to change the SQL string to:

```
wql = "Select * From Win32_MappedLogicalDisk"
```

This does not produce any results.

Comment: The list will be used in the application, so I was thinking to pull the information from the logged in user's registry. But which registry keys are created that contain the remote drives information?

Comment: Review https://superuser.com/questions/769679/powershell-get-list-of-folders-shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the host `\\tsclient` to search. A remote drive `D` will be reached with:

```
\\tsclient\D
```

So, the very simple method would be to call `Dir` in a loop using the possible drive letters at the client, like:

```
? Dir("\\tsclient\D\", vbDirectory)
```

This will return a folder at the client or raise an error if `D` is not shared.

Or just to raise an error:

```
Dir "\\tsclient\D\", vbDirectory
```

Comment: YES! It works, I had a typo first, but after I corrected it, this works fine!
Thank you Gustav. This was a major issue for me. I can sleep again... ! :)